# React application breaks after downloading SVG through d3_save_svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I am prototyping a simple `React` App where the user is able to interact with an `SVG` generated with `d3` and download the SVG that results from their interaction (though React isn't especially useful at the prototyping stage, it will be required eventually once the prototype is expanded upon).

I stumbled upon the `d3-save-svg` library (https://github.com/edeno/d3-save-svg) which is really handy and I am testing it in my prototype to see if I can rely on it looking forward.

The prototype is working "well" in the sense that the user is able to:

1. Interact with the `SVG`, and
2. Download the `SVG` resulting from their interaction.

However downloading the `SVG`, which relies on `d3-save-svg`, appears to break further interactivity with the `SVG`, which is unintended. The user is still able to redownload the `SVG` but cannot interact with the `SVG` anymore.

Can anyone:

- Help me understand what's going on, and/or
- Propose a fix that would allow the user to, pass the first download, interact further with the `SVG` and redownload the result of their further interactions?

Here is the prototype code (https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-hellman-qcppyd):

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import d3_save_svg from "d3-save-svg";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3
      .select(ref.current)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500);

    svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 400)
      .attr("cy", 300)
      .attr("r", 100)
      .attr("fill", "blue");

    svg
      .append("text")
      .text("Move")
      .attr("x", 100)
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("click", function () {
        svg.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function () {
          return d3.select(this).attr("cx") - 10;
        });
      });

    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr(
        "d",
        "M896 672q119 0 203.5 84.5t84.5 203.5-84.5 203.5-203.5 84.5-203.5-84.5-84.5-203.5 84.5-203.5 203.5-84.5zm704-416q106 0 181 75t75 181v896q0 106-75 181t-181 75h-1408q-106 0-181-75t-75-181v-896q0-106 75-181t181-75h224l51-136q19-49 69.5-84.5t103.5-35.5h512q53 0 103.5 35.5t69.5 84.5l51 136h224zm-704 1152q185 0 316.5-131.5t131.5-316.5-131.5-316.5-316.5-131.5-316.5 131.5-131.5 316.5 131.5 316.5 316.5 131.5z"
      )
      .attr("transform", "translate(200 100) scale(0.02)")
      .attr("class", "snap-button")
      .attr("fill", "#1976d2")
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      /* .html(iconHtml) */
      .on("click", function () {
        var config = {
          filename: "customFileName"
        };

        d3_save_svg.save(d3.select("svg").node(), config);
      });
  });

  return <div ref={ref} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `d3_save_svg` modifies the DOM before it exports the svg, adding a number of things to it including styles. It seems that, since this happens outside of react's rendering cycle, React looses its refs and looses track of the SVG's desired implicit state.

A solution is to base the export on a clone version of the `SVG` which you can then remove right after the export, thereby guaranteeing the copy is never actually visible to the user (if desired, there can be other ways to do ensure the user never sees the copy, such as locating the copy outside of the viewbox).

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import d3_save_svg from "d3-save-svg";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3
      .select(ref.current)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500);

    svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 400)
      .attr("cy", 300)
      .attr("r", 100)
      .attr("fill", "blue");

    svg
      .append("text")
      .text("Move")
      .attr("x", 100)
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("click", function () {
        svg.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function () {
          return d3.select(this).attr("cx") - 10;
        });
      });

    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr(
        "d",
        "M896 672q119 0 203.5 84.5t84.5 203.5-84.5 203.5-203.5 84.5-203.5-84.5-84.5-203.5 84.5-203.5 203.5-84.5zm704-416q106 0 181 75t75 181v896q0 106-75 181t-181 75h-1408q-106 0-181-75t-75-181v-896q0-106 75-181t181-75h224l51-136q19-49 69.5-84.5t103.5-35.5h512q53 0 103.5 35.5t69.5 84.5l51 136h224zm-704 1152q185 0 316.5-131.5t131.5-316.5-131.5-316.5-316.5-131.5-316.5 131.5-131.5 316.5 131.5 316.5 316.5 131.5z"
      )
      .attr("transform", "translate(200 100) scale(0.02)")
      .attr("class", "snap-button")
      .attr("fill", "#1976d2")
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      /* .html(iconHtml) */
      .on("click", function () {
        var config = {
          filename: "customFileName"
        };

         let svgExport = d3.select(".svg").clone(true)
         d3_save_svg.save(svgExport.node(), config);
         svgExport.remove()
      });
  });

  return <div ref={ref} />;
}
```